# Responsive Email not working on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design, html-email

I am new to responsive designs, so I apologize in advance. I am taking my current emails, and making a section of them responsive. I have a 3 column email, and would like it to stack to one column, and make the text larger. I have gotten successful results via the browser, but once I check it on my iPhone 5, I get nothing. I have sent to an AOL, Gmail, and Outlook account, and none react to the one column. I listed my style below. Again, I am new to the whole media queries, so I apologize if it looks ridiculous.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    table.container {width: 100% !important; padding:0 4px;}    
            table.container {
        text-align: center !important;
        font-size:20px !important;
    }   

    .templateColumnContainer{
        display:block !important;
        width:100% !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {

    table.container {width: 100% !important; padding:0 4px;}    
    table.container {
        text-align: center !important;
        font-size:20px !important;  
    }

    .templateColumnContainer {
        display:block !important;
        width:100% !important;
    }
}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    table.container {width: 100% !important; padding:0 4px;}    
    table.container {
        text-align: center !important;
        font-size:20px !important;  
    }

    .templateColumnContainer {
        display:block !important;
        width:100% !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

    table.container {width: 280px !important; padding:0 4px;}   
    table.container {
        text-align: center !important;
        font-size:20px !important;  
    }

    .templateColumnContainer {
        display:block !important;
        width:100% !important;
    }
}


            </style>
        </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gmail, AOL and Outlook.com all [do not support](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) media queries. Try sending it to your default mail reader on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

It's wise to change to fluid design.
1. Create a wrapper table 100% width.
2. Nest a container table which is 100% in width BUT has a table cell with a width and max-width that holds your mail design width. Be sure to put an align=center on this TD as well.

Inside this container table your start building your mail. Use align attributes to create elements to move once the viewport changes.

You actually can use media queries for some mobile devices. Put  in the head and you can use media queries based upon viewport change.

Answer (score 0):

the best way make your email responsive :
Add metas :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
```

If you need sans-serif font for outlook, put this a the and of the head :

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style type="text/css">
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, span, td, em, strong {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Make a table based design.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;margin:0 auto;">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="center">
        <table class="fullwidth" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="borde-r-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;margin:0 auto;">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:5px;line-height:5px; height: 10px">&nbsp;</td> <!-- paddign & margin not supported by Outlook -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" align="center">
                    <!-- Add fun here -->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:5px;line-height:5px; height: 10px">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Add class `fullwidth` on tables that need to fit the full size in a media querie (480 for example) :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .fullwidth,
    .fullwidth tbody,
    .fullwidth tbody > tr,
    .fullwidth tbody > tr > td,
    .fullwidth tbody > tr > th,
    table[class=fullwidth],
    table[class=fullwidth] tbody,
    table[class=fullwidth] tbody > tr,
    table[class=fullwidth] tbody > tr > td,
    table[class=fullwidth] tbody > tr > th
    td[class=main-border] {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        min-width: 100% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        display: block !important;
        clear: both;

        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
}
```

Images src MUST be with absolute address with HTTPS (google proxy)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a fluid-hybrid approach. Use nested table columns that use `max-width` along with media queries for clients that support them.

- Build a basic skeleton that works for all clients. The guys over at Email on Acid created a beautiful template that works seamlessly, in my experience across multiple devices (it's scary that this one template works so well). It has served me well over the years as a boilerplate, with minor tweaks here and there for improving support for HTML email support over the years. Download it [here](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-marketing/our-gift-to-you-a-free-fluid-hybrid-email-template). They've gone with a fluid-hybrid approach that uses `max-width` for the table columns.
- Outlook doesn't support `max-width`, therefore you'd need to resort to conditionals for Outlook. Read about it [here](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/). The link to the template I mentioned above has conditionals written for it.
- Write media queries for email clients that support them. Refer to them [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).